# Iterating and searching for element in n-dimensional nested array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, data-structures, data-manipulation, array-algorithms

here is an array presented

```
    id: 0,
    parent: 'p1',
    children: [
        {
            id: 1,
            parent: 'p2',
            children: [
                {
                    id: 3,
                    parent: 'p4',
                    children: []
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            parent: 'p3',
            children: [
                {
                    id: 4,
                    parent: 'p5',
                    children: []
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to search an element based upon the id value, and remove it from the array and
replace it with empty array

for example, if I pass

```
let childTobeReplaced = childrenCollector(4, treeData.children);
```

the result must be

```
{
    id: 0,
    parent: 'p1',
    children: [
        {
            id: 1,
            parent: 'p2',
            children: [
                {
                    id: 3,
                    parent: 'p4',
                    children: []
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            parent: 'p3',
            children: []
        }
    ]
}
```

and childTobeReplaced must be equal to

```
{
    id: 4,
    parent: 'p5',
    children: []
}
```

The solution I implemented is as under

```
function childrenCollector(sourceId, nestedarray) {
    for (let index = 0; index < nestedarray.length; index++) {
        console.log(nestedarray[index].id)
        if (nestedarray[index].id === sourceId) {
            let childArray = nestedarray[index];
            nestedarray[index] = []
            return childArray;
        }
        if (nestedarray[index].children.length > 0) {
            return childrenCollector(sourceId, nestedarray[index].children);
        }else{

        }
    }
}
```

In this I am able to iterate through id 1 and id 3 but not able to find rest of the elements
. Can someone present me with some guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function will `return` in the first iteration of the loop when the object has children, which means that the rest of the array is not inspected. That's not what you want. Only exit the loop when you are positive that the element was found by the recursive call.

Secondly, `nestedarray[index] = []` is not removing the index from `nestedarray`. It merely replaces the reference to an object at that index with one to an empty array.

Here is a possible implementation:

```js
function childrenCollector(sourceId, nestedArray) {
    const i = nestedArray.findIndex(({id}) => id === sourceId);
    let found;
    if (i > -1) [found] = nestedArray.splice(i, 1)
    else nestedArray.some(({children}) => 
         found = childrenCollector(sourceId, children)
    );
    return found;
}

// Example data from the question
const treeData = {id: 0,parent: 'p1',children: [{id: 1,parent: 'p2',children: [{id: 3,parent: 'p4',children: []},]},{id: 2,parent: 'p3',children: [{id: 4,parent: 'p5',children: []},]}]};

const childTobeReplaced = childrenCollector(4, treeData.children);
console.log(childTobeReplaced);
console.log(treeData);
```

#### Explanation:

With `findIndex` the code tries to find the `id` in the given array. The callback function uses destructuring to let `id` be the property of the iterated object. When the callback function returns true, the `findIndex` iteration stops, and the corresponding index is assigned to `i`. If there was no match, `i` will be set to -1.

If there was a match, `splice` will extract that element from the array at that index, and will return an array of removed elements. Since there is only one removed element, that array will have just one element. This element is assigned to `found`, again using destructuring assignment.

If there was no match, then the array is iterated again, but now to make the recursive calls. For this iteration `some` is used, which also will stop the iteration as soon as there is success. In each iteration, `found` is set to the result from the recursive call. As soon as this is an object (indicating something was found), the loop exits.

In either case the `found` object (if any) is returned, or else `undefined`.

Comment: this returned element having id 2 instead of 4

Comment: I see. That is now fixed.

Comment: could you please explain your approach that will be very much helpful

Comment: Added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple immutable solution:

```
let remove = (node, id) => ({
    ...node,
    children: node.children
        .filter(child => child.id !== id)
        .map(child => remove(child, id))
})
```

Given a node, it removes children with the given id and then applies the same procedure to each remaining child.

Comment: Note that the asker wants the function to return the removed node.